# sqlite - how do I get a one row result back? (luaSQLite3)

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

How can I get a single row result (e.g. in form of a table/array) back from a sql statement.  Using Lua Sqlite (LuaSQLite3). For example this one:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='myTable';
```

So far I note:

- using "nrows"/"rows" it gives an iterator back
- using "exec" it doesn't seem to give a result back(?)

Specific questions are then:

Q1 - How to get a single row (say first row) result back?

Q2 - How to get row count? (e.g. num_rows_returned = db:XXXX(sql))

Comment: What is the "first row"? How do you define that, since rows in SQL tables are unordered?

Comment: If you just want one result you can use LIMIT 1.It is better to use orderby or you will get an arbitrary record

Comment: @NicolBolas  - I'm wanting to test if there are any rows really, so re my question I thought I would ask how to get a single row.  But anything that makes it easy to tell if there are any rows would be good

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan - ok note this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of getting the returned count:

```
> require "lsqlite3"
> db = sqlite3.open":memory:"
> db:exec "create table foo (x,y,z);"
> for x in db:urows "select count(*) from foo" do print(x) end
0
> db:exec "insert into foo values (10,11,12);"
> for x in db:urows "select count(*) from foo" do print(x) end
1
>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a single row use the `db:first_row` method.  Like so.

```
row = db:first_row("SELECT `id` FROM `table`")
print(row.id)
```

In order to get the row count use the SQL `COUNT` statement.  Like so.

```
row = db:first_row("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS count FROM `table`")
print(row.count)
```

**EDIT:** Ah, sorry for that.  Here are some methods that should work.

You can also use `db:nrows`.  Like so.

```
rows = db:nrows("SELECT `id` FROM `table`")
row = rows[1]
print(row.id)
```

We can also modify this to get the number of rows.

```
rows = db:nrows("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS count FROM `table`")
row = rows[1]
print(row.count)
```

Comment: this would be perfect, however in LuaSQLite3 it seems this isn't available :(  I'm looking at http://luasqlite.luaforge.net/lsqlite3.html

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the iterator you get back from the `rows` or whichever function you use. Except you put a `break` at the end, so you only iterate once.

Getting the count is all about using SQL. You compute it with the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ...
```

This will return one row containing a single value: the number of rows in the query.

Comment: thanks - re (a) break at end - ok understand, and (b) re "select count..." the only problem here is I'm not sure how to return this to a variable in Lua Sqlite?   i.e. return it as a Lua number.  The luasqlite doco is at http://luasqlite.luaforge.net/lsqlite3.html it would seem.

Comment: The documentation is also at the new site http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what I'm using in my project and works well for me.

```
local query = "SELECT content FROM playerData WHERE name = 'myTable' LIMIT 1"

local queryResultTable = {}

local queryFunction = function(userData, numberOfColumns, columnValues, columnTitles)

    for i = 1, numberOfColumns do

        queryResultTable[columnTitles[i]] = columnValues[i]

    end

end

db:exec(query, queryFunction)

for k,v in pairs(queryResultTable) do

    print(k,v)

end
```

You can even concatenate values into the query to place inside a generic method/function.

```
local query = "SELECT * FROM ZQuestionTable WHERE ConceptNumber = "..conceptNumber.." AND QuestionNumber = "..questionNumber.." LIMIT 1"
```