# Corona Lua SQLite getting a single row?

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I'm grabbing a single row like this

```
local thisRow 
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE level='" .. myapp.level .. "' LIMIT 1") do
    thisRow = row
end
```

which is really dumb.. ive searched the documentation but i havent found anything like `db:exec("query"):getFirst()`

Any way to just grab a single record?

Comment: anything in this post helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343255/sqlite-how-do-i-get-a-one-row-result-back-luasqlite3

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this `db:nrows("query")[1]`